# Spring Boot, Security login infinite query

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement spring security in my spring boot app.
but whenever I login, i am getting and infinite query and eventually resulting to stackoverflow error.

```
Hibernate: select useraccoun0_.id as id1_1_, useraccoun0_.email as email2_1_, useraccoun0_.first_name as first_na3_1_, useraccoun0_.last_name as last_nam4_1_, useraccoun0_.password as password5_1_, useraccoun0_.status as status6_1_ from user_account useraccoun0_ where useraccoun0_.email=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.userid as userid1_1_0_, roles0_.roleid as roleid2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roleid=role1_.id where roles0_.userid=?
Hibernate: select user0_.roleid as roleid2_0_0_, user0_.userid as userid1_2_0_, useraccoun1_.id as id1_1_1_, useraccoun1_.email as email2_1_1_, useraccoun1_.first_name as first_na3_1_1_, useraccoun1_.last_name as last_nam4_1_1_, useraccoun1_.password as password5_1_1_, useraccoun1_.status as status6_1_1_ from user_roles user0_ inner join user_account useraccoun1_ on user0_.userid=useraccoun1_.id where user0_.roleid=?
```

Here is my **User DTO**

```
@Data
@ToString(exclude = "password")
@Entity
public class UserAccount {

    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleID"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status status;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
    }
}
```

and Here is my **Role DTO**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserAccount> user = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Here is my **CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Component
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserAccount user = repository.findByEmail(email);

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}
```

and here is my **SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(UserAccount.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/built/**", "/css/main.css","/css/vendor/flexboxgrid.css").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
```

I really can't find what's wrong with my configuration. Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what's wrong and finally got it to work. I changed `Set` to `Collection`. It seems like a hibernate bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_role` table shouldn't have a relationship to `user_account` table. `user_account` should have a `one to many` relationship with `user_role`. You're getting infinite loop because `user_role` has a circular relationship with `user_account`.

Comment: but if declare it `one to many` then it won't have a third table.

Comment: Third table ? didn't get you

Comment: the third table for the `user_roles`, it contains `userid` and `roleid`. for example, `user1` can have `role1` and `role2` , and `user2` can have `role1` only.

Comment: How else is the `user_account` going to persist it's relationship with the `user_role` ? Certainly this mapping can not be present in either of the tables.

Comment: finally got it to work. i just changed `Set` to `Collection`. it seems like a hibernate bug. Thanks for the help tho.